# Kubuntu - newly created user delayed from showing

Tags: kubuntu, user-management, adduser

Using the GUI in Kubuntu, I am creating a new user (we will call it newuser1).  I enter the username, and valid password, then hit apply.

Nothing happens.

I try creating a 2nd new user, thinking the name is wrong (we will call it newuser2).  I enter a different username and valid password, then hit apply.

After creating newuser2, THEN newuser1 shows up in the list of users.  But newuser2 does not show up.  This issue is flaky, shows up in one system, but not another.  But I have seen it enough to tell the student to enter a 2nd new user, which forces the 1st new user through the system.  Looks like an issue with cache.  This problem doesn't happen when a new user is created in the Shell.

I am teaching a Desktop Linux class, and we teach people new to Linux how to do tasks in the GUI and in the Shell.  I want them to see how they can do things faster once they get comfortable with Shell.  90% of the students are new to Desktop Linux, so bridging that gap between Wapple & Linux has to include the GUI as part of that learning process.

But I have seen this new user creation phantoms appear before, over the past year.  We are using the latest version of Kubuntu 16.04.

Thoughts?

JJL